# How to add new mode in chatGPT-4? For example "Advanced Data Analyses"

Tags: chatgpt, gpt, openai, computer-programming, code

When I create a new chat, at the top of the chatGPT version selection window a dropdown **list of available modes** appears when I hover over GPT-4 tab. Right now I only have 3 options: `Default`, `Browse with Bing`,  `DALLE-3`. [image: Screen]

How do these appear, and how can I add new ones? How do I connect additional plugins?

I mainly use chatGPT for two purposes:

1. Working with code (implementation, hints, refactoring, reviewing, error detection)
2. Translating foreign texts (from various Slavic languages to English and vice versa)

Which modes/plugins/models are best for these purposes to get the best experience? Which modes will work? Where can I get them and how do I connect them?

For code I've heard a very good mode `Advanced Data Analyses`. But I don't have it by default

Comment: “*I've heard a very good mode `Advanced Data Analyses`*” Does the source explain how to perform this?

Comment: I saw mode `Advanced Data Analyses` with one of my friends. This mode is so helpful for working with code. ChatGPT can write much more effective code and work with data in this mode for various tasks. Do you work with code and data in just default mode?

Comment: Obviously not, I wouldn't be asking about it here otherwise